# How to remove a file from a pull request in Sourcetree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I accidentally pushed some submodels during a pull request.  Is there a way to remove them after the fact?

Comment: I don't know anything about sourcetree, but elsewhere (github, gitlab, launchpad, ...) you simply modify your branch locally and then update the pull request by force pushing (`git push -f`) to the remote branch associated with your pull request.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you cannot remove a file from a PR in Sourcetree as this is a GitHub specific feature that is not available in sourcetree.

The best solution for your problem would be to create another commit on top of that branch that simply deletes those files. After pushing those changes the PR does not contain these changes any more. Nothing bad can happen in this scenario.

If you really want to remove those files completely, you have to proceed as proposed by larsks and edit this branch locally and force push it. I definitely do not recommend this option as it may screw the history of a teammate that already pulled your changes.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, they just didn't want to be reflected as: **File changes** (regardless of the commits to be added).

I just deleted the files and performed **Commit/Push.**

When updating the Pull Request, they are no longer reflected (as if they were never added).

I hope this can be useful.